# How to bind color into my XAML

Tags: wpf, listview, datagridviewcolumn

I have this view model:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Status;
    public StatusMsg StatusMessage;
    private Brush _statusBrushes;

    public Brush StatusBrushes
    {
        get
        {
            switch (StatusMessage)
            {
                case StatusMsg.Cancel:
                    return Brushes.Red;

                case StatusMsg.InProcess:
                    return Brushes.Blue;

                case StatusMsg.Done:
                    return Brushes.Green;

                default:
                    return Brushes.Green;
            }
        }
        set { _statusBrushes = value; }
    }

    public enum StatusMsg
    {
        Cancel,
        Done,
        InProcess,            
    }
}
```

Now i have this `GridViewColumn`:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Status">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Status}" Foreground="Yellow" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

So as you can see this `GridViewColumn` color is yellow and i want to change it according my `StatusMsg` (my enum) so my question is how to bind my color into my `XAML` ?

Comment: We're missing a lot of code here. Where is the `Status` property located? Can you post both your view model and model code?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating an [`IValueConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) that is able to convert your enum value to the appropriate color and then your binding would look something like:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Status">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Status}" 
              Foreground="{Binding Path=StatusColor, Converter={StaticResource MyStatusColorConverter}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

You will of course also need to create the resource, here's a tutorial that a quick bing search turned up: http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html